# Textbox validation math formula

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, customvalidator

I have 3 textboxes where i need users to key in numbers. I need the rules as follows:

TB3 must be not be more than TB2 and TB1 and TB2 must not be more than TB1

TB3 <= TB2 + TB1
TB2 <= TB1

How can i do that for each textbox validator?

Comment: Have you even tried anything?

Comment: Nope because im quite confused on it

Comment: Well then. try something, anythings better than nothing. get the input get the boxes parse the numbers check the data perform the validation

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CustomValidator control which has a property called  ClientValidationFunction 
you can create a javascript function "ValidateNumbers" and assign its name to clientValidationFunction property.
further in function ValidateNumbers you can fetch existing values of TB, TB2 and TB3 and write your custom logic to validate them and set the value of  args.IsValid = true or false

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

In the event handler you are using to submit the information, I'm assuming a button click, just put a couple lines of code in:

```
if(Convert.ToDouble(TB3.Text) <= Convert.ToDouble(TB2.Text) && Convert.ToDouble(TB3.Text) <= Convert.ToDouble(TB1.Text) && Convert.ToDouble(TB2.Text) <= Convert.ToDouble(TB1.Text))
{
  //Preform your function
      MessageBox.Show("It works");
}
else{
     MessageBox.Show("Error in entered information");
}
```

I usually do this because I prefer the flexibility this gives me to validators.